# can we change default gateway and interface in mac through commandline

Tags: macos, interface, routes, gateway

We can see default gateway and interface of MAC by using following command

`route -n get default`

I know that this is possible in linux
 and can be achieved by following commands

`route change default -interface $INTF
 route change 192.168.0.0/16 -interface $INTF`
But these are not working in MAC. My objective is to change the Default Gateway and interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`networksetup`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) utility should be able to do what you want.

For example, to manually set up the standard Ethernet interface with an IP of `192.168.100.100`, subnet of `255.255.255.0` and gateway of `192.168.100.1`:

```
networksetup -setmanual "Ethernet" 192.168.100.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.1
```

You might also be interested in the `-setadditionalroutes` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an instance where someone setup dual default routes

```
grant@dd08-mac:~[20220909-15:59][#8625]% netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            10.17.124.1        UGScg             en0       
default            10.1.78.1          UGScIg        bridge0       
10.1.78/24         link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.1/32       link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.1          link#16            UHLWIir       bridge0      !
10.1.78.24         link#16            UHLWI         bridge0      !
10.1.78.58/32      link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.58         36.6a.e9.47.a5.80  UHLWIi            lo0       
10.1.78.255        ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff  UHLWbI        bridge0      !
-snip-
```

I reset the interface with networksetup - this deleted the extra route

```
grant@dd08-mac:~[20220909-16:04][#8885]% sudo networksetup -setmanual Ethernet 10.17.124.78 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0
Password:
grant@dd08-mac:~[20220909-16:11][#8924]
```

and the extra route is gone

```
grant@dd08-mac:~[20220909-16:11][#8964]% netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            10.1.78.1          UGScg         bridge0       
10.1.78/24         link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.1/32       link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.1          link#16            UHRLWIir      bridge0     19
10.1.78.58/32      link#16            UCS           bridge0      !
10.1.78.58         36.6a.e9.47.a5.80  UHLWIi            lo0       
10.17.124/24       link#9             UCS               en0      !
10.17.124.5        0:25:90:55:6d:e3   UHLWIi            en0   1191
10.17.124.78/32    link#9             UCS               en0      !
-snip-
```